# Data migration tool for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm looking for a data migration tool for MongoDB, 
something like Liquibase or Flyway, that is compatible with Mongo 3.0.

Any recommendations?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to migrate "by hand" just download MongoChef, you can select database and copy and paste it anywhere else

Comment: MongoDB is now supported in Flyway v10.1.0

Answer (score 4):

Mongeez seems to be a dead project. You can try [Mongobee](https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee) instead.

Comment: It seams that Mongobee is dead too, One of Its' forks with the name of [Mongock](https://github.com/cloudyrock/mongock)

Answer (score 2):

I have used **Mongobee** while working with MongoDB and neeeded something similar to flyway. Does the job and easy to configure.

Add Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.mongobee</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongobee</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

you will need to create the bean for Mongobee in your context xml file

```
<bean id="mongobee" class="com.github.mongobee.Mongobee">
 <constructor-arg ref="mongo"/>
 <property name="dbName" value="${mongo.databaseName}"/>
 <property name="enabled" value="true"/>
 <property name="changeLogsScanPackage" value="basepackagewherechangesetispresent"/>
```

Now add changeset class

```
@ChangeLog(order = "1")
public class DatabaseChangeLog {

@ChangeSet(order = "101", id = "somelogicalnameforthischangeset", author = "nameofpersonwhodidthischange")
public void setupSeedData(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) { 
   // run your datasetup, prefill,migration here.
}
```

And just like flyway, it also maintains the schema version table, so that same change set does not ran again in same environment.

Answer (score 1):

I built a quick command line tool intended to update database during deployment.

It uses dotnet core and runs on windows/linux/macos.

As of now, it allows to export/import/delete/drop and eval any javascript.
https://github.com/Socialtalents/SocialTalents.MongoSync/

PS: It is 3 days old so in case you find a bug please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Quite old question, but for others looking for an answer:

You can try out Mongeez (https://github.com/mongeez/mongeez). Still the only one I found.

Answer (score 0):

There a great tool called [MongoSyphon](https://github.com/johnlpage/MongoSyphon) developed by one of Mongo's consulting engineers, which includes joins etc and is highly configurable.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across Ox ([blog post](https://medium.com/@fernandojnn/ox-versioning-mongodb-databases-392de3eb9875), [repo](https://github.com/fernandonogueira/ox)).  Looks promising.